# Wordpress get_template_directory_uri is not working with a child theme

Tags: wordpress

So I am using `mr tailor` together with a child theme.
The theme folders are named accordingly: `mrtailor` and `mrtailor-child`.

But in the theme manager in dashboard they are called: `Mr. Tailor` and `Mr. Tailor Theme`. Just mentioned this, because it usually adds the `child` in the end instead of a `theme`.

The problem is that I override some of the function and place them into the child theme. The scripts run well, bet the `get_template_directory_uri()` returns the parent theme's uri.

Here is an example of one of the overriden functions if that is going to help:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="large-10 text-center large-centered columns">

        <div class="cart-empty-banner cart-wishlist-empty-banner">
            <img id="cart-empty-img" alt="cart-empty-image"  width="480" height="233"  src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/empty_cart_black.png'; ?>" data-interchange="[<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/empty_cart_black.png'; ?>, (default)], [<?php echo get_template_directory_uri() . '/images/empty_cart_black_retina.png'; ?>, (retina)]">
        </div>

        <p class="cart-empty cart-wishlist-empty"><?php _e( 'Your cart is currently empty.', 'mr_tailor' ) ?></p>

        <?php do_action( 'woocommerce_cart_is_empty' ); ?>

        <p class="return-to-shop"><a class="wc-backward" href="<?php echo get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Return To Shop', 'mr_tailor' ) ?></a></p>

    </div><!-- .large-10-->
</div><!-- .row-->
```

Any help or guidance is much appreciated.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

That is what [`get_template_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_template_directory_uri) do, it retrieve the template directory of a theme, or in other words, the **parent** theme

For child themes, you should be using [`get_stylesheet_directory_uri()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_stylesheet_directory_uri) which retrieves the stylesheet directory path, which is used by **child** themes

Comment: what about the JS path?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `get_stylesheet_directory()` to include any file in your child theme `functions.php` file. Here is an example;

```
include (get_stylesheet_directory() . '/myWidget/newsWidget.php');
where I have `newsWidget.php` file in myWidget folder which is in childtheme directory.
```

Remember the crucial difference between

`get_stylesheet_directory()` and `get_stylesheet_directory_uri()` 
where the former will redirect you to child Theme directory while latter will redirect you to `style.css` file of your child theme.